# Page limits in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, memoir, geometry

With tikz, I am drawing a line from an extremity of the A4paper to the other as follows:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (current page.south) -- (current page.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The pdf produced has two pages. A first one blank, the other one with the vertical line that I want.

Furthermore, if I draw two "limit lines" consecutively, as

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (current page.south) -- (current page.north);
    \draw (current page.east) -- (current page.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

a second blank page is produced, after the drawing  (so the result is blank page-drawing-blank page) ?!

I chose the `memoir` class, with the `geometry` package:

```
\documentclass[oneside, english, 10pt, a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=0pt]{geometry}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please provide a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?

Comment: You need [remember picture,overlay] to use the (current page) anchors.

Comment: ... and compile the document twice to get the correct result.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: thank you, it worked! If you want to write it as an answer, I'll mark it as one. I'm also not sure btw, why drawing a line from (0,0) to (21, -29.7) is not the same as drawing a line from (north west) to (south east).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally everything in a tikzpicture is put into a bounding box which is then treated by LaTeX like any other box.  All you can control is the baseline.

Using `overlay` is like using `\smash{\rlap{...}}` with the origin placed at the baseline of the current text position.  It also turns off the bounding box computation.

Using `remember picture` saves the origin location (which is unknown until the page is ready to ship out) to the aux file.  On the next pass it reads this value and is able to determine where the `(current page)` anchors are.  It also reads the origin location for every other tikzpicture (using `remember picture`) or tikzmark on the page and is able to determine the relative position of their anchors as well.

```
\documentclass[oneside, english, 10pt, a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw (current page.south) -- (current page.north);
    \draw (current page.east) -- (current page.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```